# Write PL/SQL code to generate Armstrong number from 1 to 500

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting output as a = 1. I have taken a for loop from 1 to 500 and while loops inside the outer for loop.

```
declare
    n number;
    s number:=0;
    r number;
    len number;
    m number;
begin
    for a in 1..500 loop
        m:=a;
        n:=a;
        len:=length(to_char(n));
        
        while(n>0) loop
            r:=mod(n,10);
            s:=s+power(r,len);
            n:=trunc(n/10);
        end loop;
        
        if m=s then
            dbms_output.put_line('a='||to_char(a)');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

- `substr` splits `i` to 3 separate digits

  - `nvl` is here to avoid adding `null` value if those digits don't exist (yet)
- `power` function calculates `i`'s cube
- display `i` if it is equal to `r` (as "result")

---

```
SQL> declare
  2    r number;
  3  begin
  4    for i in 1 .. 500 loop
  5      r :=     power(to_number(substr(to_char(i), 1, 1)), 3) +
  6           nvl(power(to_number(substr(to_char(i), 2, 1)), 3), 0) +
  7           nvl(power(to_number(substr(to_char(i), 3, 1)), 3), 0);
  8
  9      if r = i then
 10         dbms_output.put_line(i);
 11      end if;
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
1
153
370
371
407

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Arithmetic version , i<=999 `r := power(floor(i/100), 3) + power(mod(floor(i/10), 10), 3) + power(mod(i,10), 3);`

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `s` and you do not need the final `IF` statement (unless you are only interested in the Armstrong numbers which equal the original number):

```sql
declare
  n number;
  s number:=0;
  r number;
  len number;
  m number;
begin
  for a in 1..500 loop
    m:=a;
    n:=a;
    s:=0;                                -- Reset s for each loop
    len:=length(to_char(n));
    while(n>0) loop
      r:=mod(n,10);
      s:=s+power(r,len);
      n:=trunc(n/10);
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line(a || '=' || s); -- Output values for every loop.
  end loop;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a4416acff186971be3fcb46d5357f792)*